# Tandem - Is there an equivalent to cURL in HP NonStop?

Tags: hp-nonstop, tandem

I need to execute a simple HTTP POST to a URL from the NonStop computer to make sure a service functions correctly. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in TACL commands to make an HTTP POST request. The TACL command POST allows you to send an HTTP POST request to a specified URL. For example:

POST url headers=content-type:text/plain
data=This is the request body